# Probability of winning a duel

Tags: probability, random-walk

Two players are competing in a game with a maximum of *n* points, where each turn **only** one player scores a point. If the first player has *a* points and the second *b*, what are the respective probabilities of winning, i.e. *a=n* or *b=n*, assuming both players have a 50% chance of winning each round?

**Example**
Player 1: 4 points
Player 2: 6 points
Game won if 7 points are reached.

Comment: The probability of **whom** winning?????

Comment: @barakmanos _Both_, I presume.

Comment: The probability that both will win is $0$, obviously!

Comment: Doesn't matter, let's say player 1 for now - the other would just be 1 - that anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability that $A$ wins is a function $f$ of $n-a$ and $n-b$ only.
Clearly, $f(0,k)=1$ for $k\ge 1$ and $f(k,0)=0$ for $k\ge 1$ ($f(0,0)$ is undefined or interpretable as $\frac12$), and we have the recursion
$$\tag1f(x,y)=\frac{f(x-1,y)+f(x,y-1)}2 $$
for $x,y\ge1$. Quite obviously, we have $f(x,y)=1-f(y,x)$ and $f(x,x)=\frac12$. For small $x,y$, this should be enough to help you compute the desired result.

**Example:**
$$f(7-4,7-6)=f(3,1)=\frac{f(2,1)+f(3,0)}2=\frac{\frac{f(1,1)+f(2,0)}2+f(3,0)}2 =\frac{\frac{\frac12+0}2+0}2=\frac18.$$
In fact, such an example with one player only one point away from a win is quite simple anyway: The other player needs to win several (here: three) times in a row ...

Comment: Can this be generalized and simplified so one can calculate the according probabilities in one's head?

Comment: very beautiful solution